# PowerShell - Loop through files and rename

Tags: powershell, scripting

newbie here. I am trying to write a PowerShell script to:

1. loop through all files in directory
2. List item
3. Get all .pdf files ONLY

   Rename them-the file names are long - over 30 chars 
   -They contain 2 numbers which I need to extract
   -Example:

   Cumulative Update 11 for Microsoft Dynamics NAV 2018 (Build 25480).pdf -> 
   RESULT : = 18CU11.pdf

I tried examples from bunch of sites and I can't seem to even loop successfully.
Either get an error - that path doesn't exist or that can't rename files as somehow loop gets a filepath and that I can't rename

```
Get-ChildItem "C:\Users\******\Desktop\PowerShell Practice" -Filter *.pdf |  #create list of files

ForEach-Object{
    $oldname = $_.FullName;
    $newname = $_.FullName.Remove(0,17); 
    #$newname = $_.FullName.Insert(0,"CU")

    Rename-Item $oldname $newname;

    $oldname;
    $newname;  #for testing
}
```

That's just latest attempt, but any other ways of doing it will be fine - as long as it does the job.

Comment: How do your original filenames look exactly?

Comment: If it says the path doesn't exist, then probably .. the path doesn't exist? You should include the *actual* output from your attempts!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this logic:

```powershell
[string]$rootPathForFiles = Join-Path -Path $env:USERPROFILE -ChildPath 'Desktop\PowerShell Practice'
[string[]]$listOfFilesToRename = Get-ChildItem -Path $rootPathForFiles -Filter '*.PDF' | Select-Object -ExpandProperty FullName
$listOfFilesToRename | ForEach-Object {
    #get the filename wihtout the directory
    [string]$newName = Split-Path -Path $_ -Leaf 
    #use regex replace to apply the new format
    $newName = $newName -replace '^Cumulative Update (\d+) .*NAV 20(\d+).*$', '$2CU$1.pdf' # Assumes a certain format; if the update doesn't match this expectation the original filename is maintained
    #Perform the rename
    Write-Verbose "Renaming '$_' to '$newName'" -Verbose #added the verbose switch here so you'll see the output without worrying about the verbose preference
    Rename-Item -Path $_ -NewName $newName 
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Check the Help for [Rename-Item](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/rename-item).  The Parameter **-NewName** requires the **name of the file** only, not the full path.

Try out this:

```
Get-ChildItem "C:\Users\******\Desktop\PowerShell Practice-Filter" -Filter *.pdf |  #create list of files

ForEach-Object{
    $oldname = $_.FullName
    $newname = $_.Name.Remove(0,17)

    Rename-Item -Path $oldname -NewName $newname

    $oldname
    $newname  #for testing
}
```

Comment: Still throws an error - Rename-Item Cannot rename the specified target, because it represents a path or device name.

Answer (score -1):

Please try this

```
Get-ChildItem -Path "C:\Users\******\Desktop\PowerShell Practice-Filter" -Filter *.pdf | Rename-Item -NewName $newname
```

Comment: and `$newname` would be the same for all files?

Comment: No, but the logic to renaming would be the same for all files.